# What is the width of a single character?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, char

I am making a fake input box so I can apply a vintage style text cursor like cmd `_`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function copy(val){
$(".copy").html(val);
$(".vintage").css("left",val.length*1.5+"ch");}
function enterCmd(e){
if(event.keyCode==13){
$('.cmdBox').val("");
copy($('.cmdBox').val());}}
</script>
   <!--So as the length of the string increases the cursor should move back and forth respectively.

   But it starts out accurately and then drifts away-->

<div class="cmdBoxy" >&gt;<span class="copy" ></span>
   <div class="vintage blink"></div>
</div>
   <input type="text" class="cmdBox" oninput="copy($('.cmdBox').val());" id="lp" onkeydown="enterCmd($('.cmdBox'))">

<style>
.vintage{
position:relative;
background-color:white;
height:25%;
width:2%;
left:1.5%;
font-size:1em;}
.cmdBoxy{
 position:relative;
top:1rem;
background-color:red;
height:1.5rem;
width:99%;}
</style>
```

How do I make it so that the cursor moves in sync with the text

Comment: Why not make a `contenteditable` instead?

Comment: There is no set width for a single character as they will all be different from character to character and from font to font. The closest you will get is `1ch` in a monopsace font..

Comment: That said, it does seem likely that a `cmd` lookalike WOULD use a monospace font.

Comment: @SebastianSimon how would `contenteditable` help ?

Comment: @Dumdum Consider two elements side-by-side: `<span class="cmdInput">Some text</span><span class="caret">_</span>`. The caret is exactly after the CMD input. No width calculation needed. If `contenteditable` was implemented correctly in this scenario, that’d be all you need.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Well this just pushes the div downward `<div><span contenteditable="true" >text here</span><div style="height:20px;width:20px;background-color:red;"></div></div>` and and why doesn't it work when the span which receives the input increases in size?

Comment: @Dumdum Nothing is pushed downward if the correct display model is used. That `<div>` needs to be `display: inline flow-root;`, or `display: inline-block;` for compatibility. There may be a lot more work involved in doing this, but ultimately, this may be the best option. I’d encourage you to explore this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a monospace font, where the width of all characters is the same. An example would be `Courier New`.

Then you can just use:

```
$(".vintage").css("left",val.length*1+"ch");}
```

You can see a snippet here:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function copy(val){
$(".copy").html(val);
$(".vintage").css("left",val.length*1+"ch");}
function enterCmd(e){
if(event.keyCode==13){
$('.cmdBox').val("");
copy($('.cmdBox').val());}}
</script>
   <!--So as the length of the string increases the cursor should move back and forth respectively.

   But it starts out accurately and then drifts away-->

<div class="cmdBoxy" >&gt;<span class="copy" ></span>
   <div class="vintage blink"></div>
</div>
   <input type="text" class="cmdBox" oninput="copy($('.cmdBox').val());" id="lp" onkeydown="enterCmd($('.cmdBox'))">

<style>
* {
font-family: 'Courier New';
}
.vintage{
position:relative;
background-color:white;
height:25%;
width:2%;
left:1.5%;
font-size:1em;}
.cmdBoxy{
 position:relative;
top:1rem;
background-color:red;
height:1.5rem;
width:99%;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly for you, It matches up and I fixed an error you made in the CSS (a stray "y"). I just matched up the fonts and adjusted the padding inside the input box to line up.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   function copy(val){
    $(".copy").html(val);
    $(".vintage").css("left",val.length*1.5+"ch");
}
function enterCmd(e){
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        $('.cmdBox').val("");
        copy($('.cmdBox').val());
    }
}
    </script>
   <!--So as the length of the string increases the cursor should move back and forth respectively.

   But it starts out accurately and then drifts away-->

<div class="cmdBoxy" >&gt;<span class="copy" ></span>
   <div class="vintage blink"></div>
</div>
   <input type="text" class="cmdBox" oninput="copy($('.cmdBox').val());" id="lp" onkeydown="enterCmd($('.cmdBox'))">
    <style>
   .vintage{
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  height:25%;
  width:2%;
  left:1.5%;
  font-size:1em;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
.cmdBox{
  position:relative;
  top:1rem;
  background-color:red;
  font-size:1em;
  height:1.5rem;
  width:99%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 8px;
}

.copy {
  font-size:1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
    </style>
```